# jQGrid: Is it possible to start the grid with the search toolbar on?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to get the jQGrid toolbar to show up on page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I believe it is possible. Try using the gridComplete option

```
gridComplete : function() {
  $("#myGridID")[0].toggleToolbar();
}
```

Comment: That was really close...I actually needed

    $('#myGridID')[0].toggleToolbar();

Thanks John! If you update the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @btelles...Sorry about that but good catch...glad I could help